# Быструю правку меток в очередь проверки новых сообщений

Tags: предложение, очередь-проверок

В очереди проверки новых сообщений нет возможности быстрой правки меток (inline tag edit). Думаю, она была бы там очень удобна.

Часто формулировка вопроса меня вполне устраивает, но вижу, что нужно добавить метку.